# What is the need to Cache a DataFrame when data already cached in local variable per session?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark. Trying to understand how **Cache** and **Persist** works.

I understand the need to cache any DataFrame if that data is referenced by other spark operations.

BUT..

I performed **WordCount** on 11GB file:

```
spark.read.textFile("file:///g:/dummy.txt")
 res1.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1))
 res3.rdd.reduceByKey.toDF
```

and got:

```
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: int]
```

When I call `res4.show` spark starts the execution and all tasks are executed.
After its completion I call `res4.show` again but this time it directly returns me the data in console.

Question is : If `res4` is available in current spark session, then do I want to do `res4.cache` even if it is readily available? If yes then what is the scope  of `res4`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code properly.

Comment: Title is not quite correct, but see the answer provided.

Comment: Can you consider the answer pls?

Answer (score -1):

This question is a little unclear, but let us try and bring some clarity with the simple example.

1) This is how you do **reduceByKey**:

```
val f = spark.read.textFile("/FileStore/tables/jjj.txt")
val g = f.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1))
val h = g.rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b).toDF()
h.show()
h.show()
```

2) `h.show()` is a special Action, but an Action none-the-less.
   The second time it can use skipped processing, the results that are already there on disk/memory and can be accessed immediately without a re-computation. E.g.:

```
(2) Spark Jobs
Job 4 View(Stages: 2/2)
Job 5 View(Stages: 1/1, 1 skipped)
```

**A more thorough explanation**

Skipped means that data can be gotten from cache(memory or disk), so no new separate Action necessary i.e. re-execution (of Stage). It depends on what you code.

There is a case of "shuffling" going on, which means caching or writing intermediate files to disk. In latter case these will be kept around until no longer req'd - e.g. RDD expires and are removed via Garbage Collection.

It's a bit more advanced, but I leave it at this as it covers the gist of it all.

Comment: can the Minus oner explain pls?

Comment: Suppose I hv another DataFrame df2 which references DataFrame 'h' for some processing. If h.show makes h to be available in cache, without explicitly calling h.cache OR h.persist, will df2.show cause 'h' to recompute? or simply pick 'h' from cache as in case of two consequent h.show h.show

Answer (score -2):

Cache/Persist  are useful when you want the data(res4) to be used in computing any other output.

Say if I have a scenario, I want to identify the words which are of 5 letters then res4 can be used directly , if it is cached or whenever you will call an action, it is recomputed.

And now  I have a request to fetch words with 10 letters then if res4 is cached , speed will be much faster as spark engine already have res4 in memory.
**If it is not cached, then will each action it will be recomputed.**

For more details , please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

Comment: So when I query res4 to filter by length of each element, still I get the result fast. Without caching res4. I still dont undertand its behaviour!

Comment: Cluster size is also one of the important factor, if you have sufficient resource to process the request then the difference would be small.

But think for a complex scenario where the output of one operation is used 100 times in the flow and to get the output it takes 1 second. So if you won't cache it.Your total time of job completion will be 100 Seconds extra as each time it will be recalculated. 
So overall , it will impact the performance as if you won't cache that, job will take 100 seconds extra to complete.